# Best way to write SQLite Search Query?

Tags: jquery, sql, sqlite, search

Best practice to write SQLite query to search for data from the table?

1. The most relevant result should be on top
2. The result should be sorted with the occurrence of the search term
3. In the case of the same occurrence,

   1. Words started with search terms should be on top.
   2. Words contain search string in the middle should come later.
   3. If multiple words found with same occurrence pattern then they should sort alphabetically.

For example, we have this dataset:

```
Borges Extra Virgin Olive Oil
Canola Oil Bottle
Extra Virgin Olive Oil - Olive Jar
Extra Virgin Olive Oil - Olive Tin
Olive Pomace Oil
Supreme Cooking Oil
```

When a search term is `O` Output should be

```
Extra Virgin Olive Oil - Olive Jar (3 Occuracne of `O` in start)
Extra Virgin Olive Oil - Olive Tin (3 Occuracne of `O` in start)
Borges Extra Virgin Olive Oil (2 Occuracne of `O` in the start and 1 in mid)
Olive Pomace Oil (2 Occuracne of `O` in the start)
Canola Oil Bottle (1 Occuracne of `O` in the start and 2 in the mid)
Supreme Cooking Oil (1 Occuracne of `O` in the start and 2 in the mid)
```

When a search term is `Ol` Output should be

```
Extra Virgin Olive Oil - Olive Jar (2 Occuracne of `Ol` in start)
Extra Virgin Olive Oil - Olive Tin (2 Occuracne of `Ol` in start)
Borges Extra Virgin Olive Oil (1 Occuracne of `Ol` in start)
Olive Pomace Oil (1 Occuracne of `Ol` in start)
Canola Oil Bottle (1 Occuracne of `Ol` in the mind)
```

When a search term is `Oli` Output should be

```
Extra Virgin Olive Oil - Olive Jar (2 Occuracne of `Oli` in start)
Extra Virgin Olive Oil - Olive Tin (2 Occuracne of `Oli` in start)
Borges Extra Virgin Olive Oil (1 Occuracne of `Oli` in start)
Olive Pomace Oil (1 Occuracne of `Oli` in start)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to calculate the occurrence of the search string. Set its column name `priority`. Then we sort all records on the bases of this search occurrence.

```
let searchTerm = 'Oil';
let searchQuery = `
   SELECT (length(trim(name)) - length(replace(trim(name), '${searchTerm}', ''))) as 'priority', *
   FROM product
   WHERE
       NAME LIKE '${searchTerm}' OR
       NAME LIKE '${searchTerm}%' OR
       NAME LIKE '% ${searchTerm}%' OR
       NAME LIKE '%${searchTerm}%'
   ORDER BY 1 DESC, NAME ASC
   LIMIT 0, 20
`;
```

**The output will be:**

```
Extra Virgin Olive Oil - Olive Jar (2 Occuracne of `Oli` in start)
Extra Virgin Olive Oil - Olive Tin (2 Occuracne of `Oli` in start)
Borges Extra Virgin Olive Oil (1 Occuracne of `Oli` in start)
Olive Pomace Oil (1 Occuracne of `Oli` in start)
```